# Non phony target behaves like a phony target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working on a boot project. In my boot root directory there is a makefile that contains among other things, the following code which confuse me:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL = all

.PHONY: all

all: xboot

xboot: $(TOP_DIR)/boot
    @echo "Building Boot" $(TOP_DIR)
    $(MAKE) -C $(TOP_DIR)/boot/src
```

Now, the problem is, that **any** time when this makefile is executed by calling `make`, the `xboot` receipt is **always** running. It seems that this `xboot` target acts like a phony target. From [GNU Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) regarding phony targets:

> Phoniness is not inherited: the prerequisites of a phony target are
>   not themselves phony, unless explicitly declared to be so.

Means that `xboot` target is not a phony one, but it's receipt is always running. I could not find anywhere an explanation for that.

Project facts- 
directory `$(TOP_DIR)/boot` contains sources and headers under `$(TOP_DIR)/boot/src` and `$(TOP_DIR)/boot/include`, directory `$(TOP_DIR)/boot` does not get `touch`ed at the build (it is not get updated)

Trying to understand the behavior I played around-
I tried `touch`ing `$(TOP_DIR)/boot`, and/or tried `touch`ing and creating file `xboot` file anywhere in the project, but behavior remains the same.

GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: I assume there actually *is* an `xboot` file created by that target? Otherwise it will always be remade.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude look at my last sentence - `Trying to understand the behavior I played around- I tried touching $(TOP_DIR)/boot, and/or tried touching and creating file xboot file anywhere on the projects, but behavior remains the same.`

Comment: It should not be "anywhere on [sic] the project", but in the same directory as the makefile you show. *And* it needs to be freshly created *and* be newer than `$(TOP_DIR)/boot`. *And* it makes no sense to have `xboot` depend on a *directory*, instead it should depend on the *file* (or files) created by `$(MAKE) -C $(TOP_DIR)/boot/src`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude about all your condition regarding `xboot` file I tried touching - true, I did it all and still behavior is unchanged. The directory dependency does not make sense to me also

Comment: Try removing the `$(TOP_DIR)/boot` prerequisite, and see if the problem persists. If it does, then confirm that your `xboot` rule contains the command `touch $@`, and then execute `make -d`. You'll get a flood of output on the screen; you can sift through it, and if you still can't find the problem you can add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`make` is not always handling folder dependencies the way you expect.

Should use a **file** dependency inside `$(TOP_DIR)/boot` like `$(TOP_DIR)/boot/.exists` or, even better, all your source files with a [`$(wildcard ...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html#Wildcard-Function) function.

Like:

```
xcode: $(widcard $(TOP_DIR)/boot/src/*.c $(TOP_DIR)/boot/src/*.h)
```

This will cause a rebuild only on code change.